# How to start foundation on windows?

Tags: ruby, zurb-foundation

I have installed Ruby, NodeJS, Bower and etc to install zurb-foundation project on windows. Project was installed successfully. How to open it in browser to begin development?

Comment: I expect something like that to be covered in [the documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/), is it not?

Comment: documentation ends before telling this :(

Comment: It seems to be a framework to include in your application that you develop using (for example) Rails, not something standalone that you can "open". For example, [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html) describes how to use it with a Rails app.

Comment: I think you are right. Just strange why foundation lets to create project itself in ruby environment but doesn't have any output to browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it for the Windows 7 if you want full access:

- Install Ruby (you can use http://rubyinstaller.org/ but dont forget to check "Add Ruby executables to your PATH")
- Install NodeJS
- Install Git
- install Ruby Development Kit
- Open the Git Bash and run: `npm install -g bower grunt-cli`  `gem install foundation` `"gem install wdm"` `gem install compass --pre`
- Navigate to the folder where you want to create demo project.
- in windows context menu(left click) select `Git Bash here` and run: `foundation new <NAME>`  it will create demo project and if you want to edit its style then also run `cd <NAME>/` `compass watch` and any change to the scss files will be compiled to the `app.css`

Comment: but how to see changes in browser?

Comment: @Gediminas you mean when you change something in css? You can get extension for browser to auto refresh css or use js lib like this one http://cssrefresh.frebsite.nl/ or do it manually with Ctrl-F5. If you about sass changes then you don't need to worry about it. When you  run `compass watch` compass will monitor sass files for change and update your css automatically.